# Is $-\log(x^2) \geq 2(1-x)$ for $x \in (0,1]$?

Tags: analysis, estimation, real-numbers

I want to show that $-\log(x^2) \geq 2(1-x)$ for $x \in (0,1]$, where $\log$ is the logarithm to base 2. How can I do that?

I tried to make an estimate by first bringing the minus to the other side and then exponientiating, getting that the above is equivalent to $x^2 \leq e^{\ln(2)2(1-x)}$ for $x \in (0,1]$. Then I wanted to cut the series expansion of $e^{\ln(2)2(1-x)}$ and show that what I get is larger than $x^2$, but I don't know how to argue that the residual that I cut away is positive.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $\ln (x^2) = 2 \ln x$. let $f(x) = \ln x - x + 1$. Find the global maximum of this function, and develop an inequality based on that.

Comment: This is not sufficient. Note that the logarithm is with respect to base 2, not the natural logarithm. Unlike the case with the natural logarithm, the function $-\log_2(x^2)$ takes values strictly below $2(1-x)$, so determining the location of the maximum of their difference is not sufficient (the location of the maximum of the difference is $1/\ln2$ and the maximum is positive).

Comment: OK, but I got it. The functions coincide for $x=1$, and they are differentiable on $(0,1]$ with the derivative of $-log(x^2)$ being lower or equal to the one of $2(1-x)$. The claim then follows from the fundamental theorem of calculus.